# Input geometry has unknown (0) SRID

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis

In the below post I make some queries and it works fine. However when I add the lines that do the coordinates conversion and the line that query the `geom` I receive the following error when I run the web-service:

```
Input geometry has unknown (0) SRID
```

I am new to Postgis. How can I fix this issue?

Code:

```
query = """  WITH data AS (
        SELECT '{featuresArray}'::json AS featuresCollection
        )
        SELECT gid,geom,type::text,properties::text,
        array_to_string(array_agg(x_4326||' '||y_4326 ORDER BY gid),',') AS g4326,
        array_to_string(array_agg(x_25832||' '||y_25832 ORDER BY gid),',') AS g25832             
        FROM (
        SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS gid,
        ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry')) AS geom,
        feature->>'type' AS type,
        feature->>'properties' AS properties,
        ST_X((ST_DumpPoints((ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry')))).geom) x_4326,       
        ST_Y((ST_DumpPoints((ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry')))).geom) y_4326,  
        ST_X((ST_DumpPoints((ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),25832)))).geom) x_25832,       
        ST_X((ST_DumpPoints((ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),25832)))).geom) y_25832

        FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(featuresCollection->'features') AS feature FROM data) AS f) j
        GROUP BY gid,type::text,properties::text,geom
        ORDER BY gid;""".format(featuresArray=featuresArray)
```

Comment: Hi there. Please add the `CREATE TABLE` and `UPDATE`/`INSERT` statements.

Comment: hi i do not do any update or insert only select

Comment: @JimJones i solved it ..it is working now..thanks for you..the hint you posted in the previous question was essential and useful

Comment: For the sake of completion I will add it here as an answer as well

Comment: @JimJones yes sure.please do

Answer (score 3):

Some PostGIS functions rely on SRS, such as [`ST_Transform`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html). You have to specify which SRS you're transforming from, otherwise the conversion script has no reference to compute the new coordinates, e.g. from `EPSG:25832` to `EPSG:4326`:

```
SELECT ST_Transform('SRID=25832;POINT(1 1)',4326);
```

.. otherwise it will raise an exception

```
SELECT ST_Transform('POINT(1 1)',4326); -- <-- WKT literal without SRS
ERROR:  ST_Transform: Input geometry has unknown (0) SRID
```

With [`ST_SetSRID`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html) you can set the SRS to geometries in case they haven't any -  as your example suggests, e.g. .

```
SELECT ST_Transform(
         ST_SetSRID('POINT(1 1)'::geometry,25832),
         4326);
```

The same principle goes for `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` / `UPDATE` statements. When creating a table we declare the SRS as follows ..

```
CREATE TABLE t (geom geometry(point,4326));
```

.. so PostGIS expects that all incoming geometries have the same SRS ..

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('SRID=4326;POINT(1 1)');
```

.. otherwise it raises an exception too

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('SRID=25832;POINT(1 1)'); 
ERROR:  Geometry SRID (25832) does not match column SRID (4326)
```

Comment: thanks i think for the sake of the question it might be good idea to mention that the problem in the question is solved be modifying ST_X((ST_DumpPoints((ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),25832)))).geom) x_25832, ST_X((ST_DumpPoints((ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),25832)))).geom) y_25832
 to be : ST_X((ST_DumpPoints((ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),4326),25832)))).geom) x_25832,             ST_Y((ST_DumpPoints((ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),4326),25832)))).geom) y_25832

Comment: @LetsamrIt I just added a shorter code snippet to make my point in a simplified manner